# Dimension and basis of set of linear codes of even weight

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory, binary

I am working on questions about coding theory. The set C is the set of all words in binary code that have an even weight and are of length n.

I have already proven that this is a linear code. Now I have to determine the dimension and basis of C. However, I cannot seem to wrap my head around this problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hint: deduce $H$ (the parity check matrix) and from that $G$
Alternatively, consider it as a systematic code in which you add an additional bit to the original $n-1$ bits, so that the total number of ones is even.

Answer (score 0):

This is the set of all even paritys.
So you can creat any message as long as the last bit is the sum of previous bits.
$H = \begin{bmatrix} 1_{n\times1}\end{bmatrix}$.
And if you solve $GH^T = 0$,
the basis will be
$G=\begin{bmatrix} I_{n-1} & 1_{(n-1)\times1}\end{bmatrix}$. So the dimension as mentioned is $n-1$.